# Switch off substitution of string resources in Androud Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, resources, settings

In the original Java file:

```
return R.string.state_connecting;
```

But Android studio 3.0.1 substitutes this:

```
return "Connecting to server";
```

How to switch off this substitution and see the original file unchanged?

This is not a duplicate, because my question is not related to xml editor. Obviously, solution from "possible duplicate" doesn't work.

Comment: Is the text grey?

Comment: No, substituted text "Connecting to server" is black.

Comment: Never mind, grey seems to be limited to the theme I'm using. Does the String replacement look just like any other String with syntax highlighting enabled?

Comment: String replacement look like any other string, but if I place the mouse pointer over the replacement, a box with the original code appears below the substituted string. If I click on the substitution, it will be replaced with the original string. But I don't want to click on every such string in code.

Comment: About syntax highlighting - if I change "Default text" color in settings - substitutions change their colors appropriately.